Killing vectors on fixed point surfaces
Given a fixed point surface $S$ for the Killing vector $\xi$ in a $4$-dimensional spacetime. If one has an orthonormal basis for this spacetime with two basis vectors tangend to $S$ and two normal to $S$, it is possible to calculate the covariant derivative of $\xi$ and contract the outcome with one of the tangential basis vectors $e^1$ at a point $p\in S$:
$\xi_{\mu;\nu} (e^i)^\mu \Big\lvert_S = \xi_{\mu,\nu}(e^i)^\mu \Big\lvert_S - \Gamma^\sigma_{\hspace{1mm}\mu\nu}\xi_\sigma(e^i)^\mu \Big\lvert_S$
According to a script of my university this should vanish on $S$. Now, I understand that the second summand should vanish, because of the deninition of a fixed point surface, but I don't see how the first summand would vanish. Thanks to everyone for helping me out! This calculation is done in order to prove that the surface gravity is constant on the Killing horizon.
